# Identifying clients on a Server-side blazor app

Tags: blazor

I would like to know if there is way of identifying clients on a Server-side blazor app.

The problem:
We are using aprox 50 handhelds based on Windows CE and we are trying to convert the app to Blazor which will be used on Android handhelds.

It is essential that each handheld identifies itself. In Windows CE, we have a config file and in this config file there is a line like: Handheld: 01

I cannot believe that we are the only company that would like to identify the clients in a manner like this.
So there should be a solution for this.

The current software for our handhelds is split in two parts.
One web service processes all data from all the handhelds (that is why the client needs to be identified)
Each handheld communicates with the web service and basically only displays data and sends out a selection.

We would like to create a server side blazor app that communicates with the existing web service.
We have already made quite some progress, but we need this identification.

Of course if it is not possible we could let the user select the handheld at startup, but that is asking for problems.

Kind regards,
Clemens Linders

Comment: The equivalent of the config file to identify a device name in the same way you are on windows CE could be to use localstorage or a cookie. This sounds similar to a previous project where we had a provisioning process for the device to set it up (and only certain accounts had permissions to do this). We could then also disable devices server side.. Worth thinking about security though, as it's stored client side (just like the config on CE, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your device to identify itself against the server you need to set id device data on it. The browser can't read a config file, but you can store this data in several places:

- Cookie
- LocalStorage
- UserAgent
- Others (?)

You should to chose one of these places and send the device id to the server accordingly.

Of course do you need sysadmin task to set the id on the device.

Try one of these methods and try to set the id on device and send the id to server, if you have issues be free to post a question with your progress and errors.

Nobody is asking about this because is not a complex issue, really easy to fix it.